# How to add Json items using forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, json

This is part of GoJS (diagramming) project and "properties" is itemArray, which is defined inside of one node in diagram.

1) This works (hard coded values):

```
properties: [
    { "property_name": "Prop1", "property_value": "100"},
    { "property_name": "Prop2", "property_value": "101" },
    { "property_name": "Prop3", "property_value": "102" }
]
```

2) This doesn't work (from data source):

```
properties: [
    data.ObjectPropertiesList.forEach(function (item, i) {
        properties.push({ "property_name": item.Item1.toString(), "property_value": item.Item2.toString() });
    })
]
```

2.1) With surrounding code:

```
myPalette.model = new go.GraphLinksModel([
    { key: "B", text: "some block", color: "blue" },
    { key: "G", text: "Macro", isGroup: true },
    { category: "circle", key: "Gc", text: "A", color: "black", group: "G", loc: "0 0" },
    {
        category: "table", key: "Ga", group: "G", loc: "60 0",
        properties: [
            data.ObjectPropertiesList.forEach(function (item, i) {
                properties.push({ "property_name": item.Item1.toString(), "property_value": item.Item2.toString() });
            })
        ]
    }
], [
    { from: "Gc", to: "Ga" }
]);
```

Comment: can you please also post the sorrounding code of the second example you have posted here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `forEach` when you want [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
properties: data.ObjectPropertiesList.map(function (item) {
    return { "property_name": item.Item1.toString(), "property_value": item.Item2.toString() };
})
```

Comment: Because it is a prime example to use `map`. You have an input array for which you want to modify each element and return the new array. This is exactly what `map` does, it transforms array items and returns them.

Answer (score 2):

Why pushing data inside var declaration ? just declare your array then push values , see below working snippet

```js
var data= {};
  data.ObjectPropertiesList = [
  {Item1:"Prop1",Item2:"100"},
  {Item1:"Prop2",Item2:"101"},
  {Item1:"Prop3",Item2:"102"},
]

properties = [];

data.ObjectPropertiesList.forEach(function (item, i) {
   properties.push({ "property_name": item.Item1.toString(), "property_value": item.Item2.toString() });
})

console.log(properties);
```

Comment: Great :) @tesicg

Answer (score 0):

```
var properties = [];
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
    var item = data[i];
    properties.push({ 
        "property_name": item.Item1.toString(), 
        "property_value": item.Item2.toString() 
    })
}
```